# Reactjs: Fetch/Preserve redux form data on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

In React, I'm trying to perform API Update call using `redux-form`. I'm able to fetch data in the edit form with the help of `initialize`. It works well. Unless user refreshes browser. In that case, I'm not able to fetch data in `initialize` since it isn't available in props/states.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
}

 componentWillMount(){
    this.props.fetchUser(this.props.params.id);
 }

render() {
 const InitlValues = {
  initialValues: {
    "name": this.props.user.name,
    "city": this.props.user.city
  }
}
const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
return(
  <form goes here..>
);
```

I did try React lifecycle method `componentWillMount` for fetching data, but it doesn't seem to work.

when user refreshes browser, it throws error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

How should I work around fetching/preserving data when user refreshes page?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a redux-form specific issue, it's a general issue with maintaining application state across refreshes in a single page application. 
With redux, you can store state that needs to persist through a refresh in localStorage - in this case, the form state. You can do this "by hand" by creating [redux middleware](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html), or there's this: https://github.com/elgerlambert/redux-localstorage

Answer (score 0):

To really avoid the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null` you need to define `defaultProps` for your class/component.

What exactly happens here, is that since your API action is async and takes time to get the data, the `this.props.user` returns `undefined` which in turn makes `this.props.user.name` throw the `Uncaught TypeError`.

Try something like this:

```
static defaultProps = {
 user: { name: '', city: '' }
}

constructor(props){
  super(props);
}

 componentWillMount(){
    this.props.fetchUser(this.props.params.id);
 }

render() {
 const InitlValues = {
  initialValues: {
    "name": this.props.user.name,
    "city": this.props.user.city
  }
}
const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
return(
  <form goes here..>
);
```

PS: if you really want to persist your redux state, you should be using Redux Middleware to store your state's portion in local storage or session storage.
More on using middleware from the creator of redux himself: [Building React Applications with Idiomatic Redux](https://egghead.io/courses/building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux)

Comment: hello, thank you for the suggestion. I did try `defaultProps` but it still throws same error..